# How to ask for help debugging when I don't know where the bug is?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently received some justified criticism for a poorly structured [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619335/can-only-select-once-in-group-of-radio-buttons).

I recognize that there is a problem with how I laid out the question, and that it's very difficult (and unappealing, and painful, and more) to help someone debug their code without being able to look at their code.

My intention (however well or poorly executed) was to ask a question about debugging the **kind** of problem I was having, because I wasn't able to provide the resources needed to debug the **exact** problem I was having. Knowing I couldn't get the solution from SO, I asked SO for direction on *how to look* for the solution. As some comments on the question emphasize, this is not necessarily an appropriate question for SO, which is much more focused on presenting and solving specific questions with concrete answers.

My question **here**, then, is **Where is an appropriate place, either in the StackExchange family or elsewhere online, to ask for help *looking* for the solution to a problem?**

**Update:**

It's been difficult to articulate exactly what I'm trying to ask for here, but thanks to a comment discussion I think there's a clearer way to summarize it:

Where's the right place to ask more general questions like "Have you ever had a problem where X won't do Y?" in search of extra experience or another pair of eyes?

Comment: How did you reach Stack Overflow in the first place? Same way (e.g. Google search) you can find other places. :) Personally, I'm not familiar with any other site nearly as professional or focused as SO.

Comment: I wonder if that question would be acceptable on SO chat? I don't usually use that feature, so I'm not sure. But I guess some people there could help to think along.

Comment: @S.L.Barth it depends on the room. Problem is that the issue is too localized for the OP as there is no repro outside of the system under test...

Comment: I don't think you'd get any better advice by asking a question than by googling something as broad as "general debugging tips". Bottom line is if you can't locate the cause of the bug, remove as much as you can and the bug will expose itself. Obviously if you removed everything so that the form was simply 2 radio buttons with no JS the bug wouldn't be present, so work back towards that point from where you are and you'll eventually remove something that will eliminate the bug. Or do the reverse and keep adding things in until the bug occurs. That's really all anyone can do.

Comment: @OGHaza I definitely appreciate that perspective. However, I also know from plenty of personal experience that there a lot of common gotchas and tricky scenarios with common ground, especially in the world of JavaScript and other UI/interaction based situations. I've benefitted greatly from asking coworkers and friends "Hey, have you ever seen a bug like this?" and showing them the error - without even showing them code. I'm not asking to turn SO or another QA site into a "How do I debug" forum - but if it's out of place to ask a broader question on SO, I want to know where to ask.

Comment: I see where you're coming from now, I missed the point a little before. I'll usually turn to the (much more experienced) guy sitting next to me and ask a super broad question like "ever had a problem where X won't do Y?" and sure enough 30% of the time he'll say "you're probably not doing Z" and immediately expose my problem. As for where to ask I have no idea :( there might be a relevant chat but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think "Have you ever had a problem where..." is a perfect capture for the *class* of question I'm asking about here.

Answer (score 3):

When I first read this, I thought you were talking about a "code-dump, how-fix" question.  The response to those questions should be to [learn how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

But that's not what your question is about. Your question is about a problem you're having with some code that you can't show the community.  I'm not sure how we can be helpful under those conditions.

Troubleshooting code problems is evidence-based and science-based; you solve them by looking at the evidence, and applying science. The code is the evidence.  Without the code, there's no possibility of a resolution.